# WPF/C# - How to update Dataset when filtering by DataView?

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, itemssource

What I need is to filter the items shown on a `DataGrid`. To do that I made the function `OnlyActiveTile` where I give the `DataTable` I need to filter. The filtering is working but there's a problem: when I click on a button to change between ItemsSource it won't update my DataSet. I'm missing something but I don't know what...

```
   private void OnlyActiveClick(DataTable DT, string ColumnName, DataGrid DG, Tile OnlyActiveTile, bool ToggleActive)
    {
        if (ToggleActive)
        {
            DG.ItemsSource = new DataView(DT.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<bool>(ColumnName) == true).CopyToDataTable());

            DT.GetChanges();
            DT.AcceptChanges();

            OnlyActiveTile.Background = Brushes.DarkSeaGreen;
        }
        else 
        {

            DG.ItemsSource = new DataView(DT);

            DT.GetChanges();
            DT.AcceptChanges();

            OnlyActiveTile.Background = Brushes.IndianRed;
        }
    }

    private void ZoneOnlyActive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (zone_onlyActive)
        {
            OnlyActiveClick(databaseDataSet.Zone,"Zone active", zoneDataGrid, ZoneOnlyActive, zone_onlyActive);
            zone_onlyActive = false;
        }
        else
        {
            OnlyActiveClick(databaseDataSet.Zone, "Zone active", zoneDataGrid, ZoneOnlyActive, zone_onlyActive);
            zone_onlyActive = true;
        }
    }
```

If I filter my results (update `ItemsSource`) and then make some changes on `DataGrid` it won't update my `DataSet`.

The problem it may exist because `databaseDataSet.Zone` is not a `DataTable` but a `defaultDataSet.ZoneDataTable`. So can someone tell me what should I change?

Comment: What do you mean with _"then make some changes on DataGrid it won't update my DataSet"_? Which changes?

Comment: This app is a configuration tool. So I'm showing a lot of DataGrids where user can change those configurations (like checkboxes). When I'm not filtering anything it is working: every change is save to my dataset, but when i'm using the filter I shown above it doesn't update my dataset. When I use the button to toggle between "full view" and "filtered view" the only changes I see is when I have "full view"... I don't know if I was clear enough...